# Iteritems a dict in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I've created with python a function for iterating through a multiple level dictionary, and execute a second function `ssocr` that needs four arguments: coord, background, foreground, type (they are the value of my keys).
This is my dictionary which is taken from a json file.

[document json](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=75fd844a1a474e8a9573671194a45882)

`

```
def parse_image(self, d):
    bg = d['background']
    fg = d['foreground']
    results = {}
    for k, v in d['boxes'].iteritems():
        if 'foreground' in d['boxes']:
            myfg = d['boxes']['foreground']
        else:
            myfg = fg
        if k != 'players_home' and k != 'players_opponent':
            results[k] = MyAgonism.ssocr(v['coord'], bg, myfg, v['type'])

    results['players_home'] = {}
    for k, v in d['boxes']['players_home'].iteritems():
        if 'foreground' in d['boxes']['players_home']:
            myfg = d['boxes']['players_home']['foreground']
        else:
            myfg = fg
        if k != 'background' and 'foreground':
            for k2, v2 in d['boxes']['players_home'][k].iteritems():
                if k2 != 'fouls':
                    results['players_home'][k] = MyAgonism.ssocr(v2['coord'], bg, myfg, v2['type'])
    return results
```

I have an error in the foreground check in the second to last iteritems, my key number overrides the key score

Comment: The exception says it: you're calling `iteritems` on a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: If you using python 3.x , you should use `dic.items` instead `dic.iteritems`

Comment: @Arman python 2; it says `unicode`

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: In any case you do not provide the input to this function so the question is essentially unanswerable; the procedure of finding out what is wrong is called **debugging**, presumably you'd want to print the value of `d['boxes']['players_home']` and `d['boxes']['players_home'][k]` before you call iteritems on them.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala , I know that was just a note

Comment: @Eldar88 **in your question itself**. Also, you should post the exact traceback of the error, showing **which** of the `iteritem`s is faulting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if k != 'background' and 'foreground':
    # do something
```

Which isn't doing the check you think it's doing. You're effectively trying

```
if (k != "background") and ('foreground'):
    # do something
```

which always evaluates to `True` (since a non empty string is considered "truthy").

Just change that line to:

```
if k not in ('background', 'foreground'):
    # do stuff
```

or do it the same way you did further up in the function (`if k != 'players_home' and k != 'players_opponent':`) and you should be in business.

Comment: Pretty embarassing error, wasted half an hour and didn't notice it. Thanks.

Comment: @Eldar88 no need to be embarrassed...happens to us all.  That said, I would highly recommend learning to use pdb (or better yet ipdb) to set a break point in your code and then step through line by line to find your problem.  It's a small time investment to learn a skill that will pay you back many times over in the future.

Comment: I still found a problem of overriding key I guess, in the last cycle